# Mutagen copy multiple times project (4 copy of the same project)

Tags: docker, magento, magento2, mutagen

I have project on Docker and I use Mutagen to sync data.
Mutage in some case copy project 3 times more and I have 4 folders with projects.

My git clone command look like this:

`git clone git@bitbucket.org:companyname/abc-magento2-store.pagename.com-multistore.git`

After this command I see one folder:

`abc-magento2-store.pagename.com-multistore`

When I run mutagen I got additional 3 folder:

1. `abc-magento2-store.pagename.com-multistore`
2. `abc-magento2-pagename.com-multistore`
3. `abc-magento2-pagename-multistore`

Looks like Mutagen have some issues with `.`

Mutagen configuration:

```yaml
# Set up code synchronization.
sync:
  defaults:
    flushOnCreate: true
    mode: "two-way-resolved"
    symlink:
      mode: "portable"
    permissions:
      defaultFileMode: "0664"
      defaultDirectoryMode: "0775"
    configurationBeta:
      permissions:
        defaultOwner: 'www-data'
        defaultGroup: 'www-data'
  code:
    alpha: "."
    beta: "docker://abc_magento_fpm/app"
    ignore:
      paths:
        - .docker
        - .idea
        - .github
        - .magento
        - '*.tar.gz'
        - docker-compose.yml
        - mutagen.yml
        - mutagen.yml.lock
        - /vendor
        - node_modules
        - "arts"
        - "var/view_preprocessed"
        - "pub/static"
        - "!pub/static/media"
        - generated/code/
  vendor:
    alpha: "./vendor"
    beta: "docker://abc_magento_fpm/app/vendor"
```

Docker Compose:

```yaml
version: '3.9'
services:
  db:
    image: 'mariadb:10.3'
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=sicretpassword
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=magento
      - MYSQL_USER=magento
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=awsomepassword
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - 'magento-code:/app:nocopy'
      - 'magento-db:/var/lib/mysql'
  redis:
    image: 'redis:5.0'
    volumes:
      - 'magento-code:/app:nocopy'
    ports:
      - 6379
  elasticsearch:
    image: 'docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.12.1'
    environment:
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - discovery.type=single-node
    volumes:
      - 'magento-elastic:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data'
  fpm:
    container_name: 'abc_magento_fpm'
    build:
      context: .docker/php
      target: fpm
    volumes:
      - 'magento-code:/app:nocopy'
      - '.docker/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini'
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
  web:
    image: 'nginx:1.19'
    volumes:
      - 'magento-code:/app:nocopy'
      - '.docker/nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf'
      - '.docker/nginx/ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl'
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    depends_on:
      - fpm
  fpm_xdebug:
    build:
      context: .docker/php
      target: fpm-debug
    volumes:
      - 'magento-code:/app:nocopy'
      - '.docker/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini'
    environment:
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: serverName=localhost
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
  deploy:
    build:
      context: .docker/php
      target: cli
    environment:
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: serverName=localhost
      COMPOSER_HOME: /app/.composer
    volumes:
      - 'magento-code:/app:nocopy'
      - '.docker/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini'
    working_dir: '/app'
    command: ['bash']
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
  mailhog:
    image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
    ports:
      - '1025:1025'
      - '8025:8025'
  cron:
    build:
      context: .docker/php
      target: cron
    volumes:
      - 'magento-code:/app:nocopy'
      - '.docker/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini'
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
volumes:
  magento-db: {  }
  magento-code: {  }
  magento-elastic:
    driver: local
```

I work at Macbook 13' Pro M1

Any ideas why it is happend and how to fix it?